# Unable to remove a HTML5 class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have made an album carousel component which will switch between two album on user click.
There are two album divs and the classes currAlbum and hiddenAlbum to identify the current and hidden album respectively. I am using JQuery to switch the two classes whenever the albums get changed. But the removeClass function is not working and the existing classes are not removed. I am showing the relevent code snippets

```
 <!-- Viewer to display photos of the album -->
<div class="viewer currAlbum">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/dc.jpg" class="album-image">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/gconvo.jpg" class="album-image">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/bconvo.jpg" class="album-image">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/sconvo.jpg" class="album-image">
</div>

<div class="viewer hiddenAlbum">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/cs.jpg" class="album-image">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/ee.jpg" class="album-image">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/mech.jpg" class="album-image">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/btech14-18ch.jpg" class="album-image">
    <img src="./src/assets/images/gallery-images/btech14-18ce.jpg" class="album-image">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.scroller .album').click((e) => {
        $('.scroller .album').unbind();

        $('.scroller .album.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.viewer.currAlbum').removeClass('.currAlbum').addClass('hiddenAlbum'); //getting issue here
        $('.viewer.hiddenAlbum').removeClass('.hiddenAlbum').addClass('currAlbum'); //getting issue here
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');

        album_images = {}
        $('.currAlbum .album-image').each((i, el) => {
            album_images[i] = el;
        });

        num = Object.keys(album_images).length;
        prev = num - 1;
        active = 0;
        next = 1;

        slider();
        init_carousel(prev, active, next);
    })
```

Please anyone help me to figure out my error

Comment: `$('.viewer.currAlbum').removeClass('.currAlbum').addClass('hiddenAlbum');` "replaces" `currAlbum` with `hiddenAlbum`. And in the next line you revert that change with `$('.viewer.hiddenAlbum').removeClass('.hiddenAlbum').addClass('currAlbum');` - That's a complicated no-op

Comment: What is this `album_images` construct for? You fill that with DOM nodes and then only use the "length" of it. `active` and `next` are always the same. So `init_carousel($(".currAlbum .album-image").length - 1, 0, 1)` does the same.

Comment: album_images array is for the switching between the two different albums which the component will render on user interaction. I am keeping all the active album images in a array for easy rendering the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I made a logical error as pointed out by Andreas in the comments.
the correct code will be

```
$('.viewer.currAlbum').removeClass('currAlbum').addClass('temp');
$('.viewer.hiddenAlbum').removeClass('hiddenAlbum').addClass('currAlbum');
$('.viewer.temp').removeClass('temp').addClass('hiddenAlbum');
```